# How to prevent searchResultsTableView from moving when searching

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7

Disclaimer: I'm targeting iOS 7. I realize UISearchDisplayController is deprecated in iOS8, but it's what I need to use.

I have the standard navigation bar hidden. Below a UIView, I have a UISearchBar and a UITableView. It looks like this:

[image]

When I attempt to search, the results filter fine, but the searchResultsTableView flies to the top of the screen.

[image]

The UISearchBar remains in the same place, but the tableView moves to cover the entire screen.

**I'm trying to prevent the tableView from moving. The desired behavior is to have both the UISearchBar and the searchResultsTableView remain in place**

What I've tried so far:

1. I looked through the delegates for searching to see if this could be easily disabled and couldn't find anything.
2. I'm using Autolayout so setting a constraint programmatically to move the top of the searchResultTableView would be logical.

(please excuse the formatting)

> -(void) searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController
>   *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
>
> ```
>  NSDictionary * views = @{ @"searchResultsTableView" : self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView};
>
> NSArray * topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
>                            constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-64-[searchResultsTableView]-|"
>                            options:0
>                            metrics:nil
>                            views:views];
> [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.superview addConstraints:topConstraint]; }
> ```

I also tried adding the constraint into "willShowSearchResultsTableView"
I'm not familiar with adding constraints programmatically so that might be the source of the issue.

3. I know that I can fix the issue by placing the TableView and SearchBar inside a ContainerView, but I'm trying to avoid doing that since that's superfluous and wasteful.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out answer number two was correct. I found in the debugger logs that `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint` was breaking the `NSLayoutConstraint` that I was trying to impose on the searchResultsTableView.

```
   self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

This line fixes the issue by turning off the mask into constraints direct conversion. I put that in viewDidLoad and then my own custom constraint was followed.